# Smarty mismatched tag

Tags: wordpress

i use a fresh install on Wordpress (all together the newest Version)

Now i want to try to register a second user on the WP-Register Page
[www.myurl.de/wp-login.php?action=register](http://www.myurl.de/wp-login.php?action=register)

And now i have this message:

---

Hallo!

Seit WordPress 5.2 gibt es eine eingebaute Funktion, die erkennt, wenn ein Plugin oder ein Theme einen fatalen Fehler auf deiner Website verursacht, und dich deswegen mit dieser automatisierten E-Mail benachrichtigt.

In diesem Fall hat WordPress einen Fehler in einem deiner Plugins, CiviCRM, abgefangen.

Besuche zunächst deine Website (http://www.myurl.de/) und überprüfe sie auf sichtbare Probleme. Besuche als nächstes die Seite, auf der der Fehler aufgetreten ist (http://www.myurl.de/wp-login.php?action=register) und prüfe, ob es sichtbare Probleme gibt.

Bitte kontaktiere dein Hosting-Unternehmen, um Unterstützung bei der weiteren Untersuchung dieses Problems zu erhalten.

Wenn deine Website fehlerhaft zu sein scheint und du nicht mehr wie gewohnt auf dein Dashboard zugreifen kannst, hat WordPress jetzt einen speziellen „Wiederherstellungsmodus“. Auf diese Weise kannst du dich sicher in deinem Dashboard anmelden und weitere Untersuchungen durchführen.

http://www.myurl.de/wp-login.php?action=enter_recovery_mode&rm_token=aRbG11nIYJQ9bwMF0hUzSd&rm_key=3WUIQAzvX2F5ESXVFPidYr

Um deine Website zu schützen, läuft dieser Link in 1 Tag ab. Aber keine Sorge: Ein neuer Link wird dir per E-Mail zugeschickt, wenn der Fehler nach Ablauf der Frist erneut auftritt.

Wenn du Hilfe bei diesem Problem suchst, wirst du möglicherweise nach einigen der folgenden Informationen gefragt:
WordPress-Version 6.0
Aktives Theme: Twenty Twenty-Two (Version 1.2)
Aktuelles Plugin: CiviCRM (Version 5.50.4)
PHP-Version 8.1.7

## Fehler-Details

Ein Fehler vom Typ E_USER_ERROR wurde in der Zeile 1100 der Datei /mnt/web733/c1/32/52347653/htdocs/ttiu4/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php verursacht. Fehlermeldung: Smarty error: [in evaluated template line 1]: syntax error: mismatched tag {/crmScope}. expected {/if} (opened line 1). (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 2338)

Answer (score 1):

I found the error, and I hope that was all now.

I have changed the following in the greeting formulas (e-mail and letter).

I have changed from:

```
Dear {contact.first_name}
```

to changed to:

```
{capture assign=p}{contact.individual_prefix}{/capture}{if $p=="Frau"}Liebe{else}Lieber{contact.first_name}
```

Now I saw in the Smarty code that I forgot the {/if} at the end.

So correct is:

```
{capture assign=p}{contact.individual_prefix}{/capture}{if $p=="Frau"}Liebe{else}Lieber{contact.first_name}{/if}
```

And now it all works again ;-)

Problem solved :-D

Answer (score 0):

php 8.1 is not supported yet by CiviCRM. Are you able to use php 8.0 instead?

Comment: Hi,
i think that's not the problem.  
I changed to 8.0 - also a critical error -> but i got no email from wordpress.  
I tried php 7.4 - same. The dialog tell me critical error -> but no mail from the system.  
  
`Es gab einen kritischen Fehler auf deiner Website. Bitte überprüfe den Posteingang deiner Website-Administrator-E-Mail-Adresse für weitere Anweisungen.  
  
Erfahre mehr über die Problembehandlung in WordPress.`
After changing back to 8.1 - same -> critical error - no e-mail. But now, i changed to 8.0. i think it will be better. but the issue should be solved.

Comment: i guess, the problem is a litte bit greater. now, i can't modify any members in civicrm. i don't know what happend. Always the same issue.

Comment: i solved it. see my "answer". by the way - i change back to php 8.1 - it will work. the problem was the smarty-code in the greetings settings. i forgot the {/if}. That's all.